# Android SOAP request containing Date gives an error: The conversion of a datetime2 data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value

Tags: java, android, .net, date, soap

Using HTTPPost I am sending the following SOAP request to a WCF .Net server:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:tem="http://tempuri.org/" xmlns:arr="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <tem:CreateExpense>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <tem:sessionID>ae56e4f8ccbf4c478db2353cdec6cb57</tem:sessionID>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <tem:parameters>
            <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
             <arr:KeyValueOfstringstring>
               <arr:Key>assignment</arr:Key>
               <arr:Value>6</arr:Value>
               <arr:Key>datestart</arr:Key>
               <arr:Value>2009-02-27T12:12:22</arr:Value>
               <arr:Key>dateend</arr:Key>
               <arr:Value>2009-02-27T12:12:22</arr:Value>
            </arr:KeyValueOfstringstring>
         </tem:parameters>
      </tem:CreateExpense>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

But the error I get is

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <s:Body>
      <s:Fault>
         <faultcode xmlns:a="http://schemas.microsoft.com/net/2005/12/windowscommunicationfoundation/dispatcher">a:InternalServiceFault</faultcode>
         <faultstring xml:lang="en-IE">An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details.</faultstring>
         <detail>
            <ExceptionDetail xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.ServiceModel" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
               <HelpLink i:nil="true"/>
               <InnerException>
                  <HelpLink i:nil="true"/>
                  <InnerException>
                     <HelpLink i:nil="true"/>
                     <InnerException i:nil="true"/>
                     <Message>The conversion of a datetime2 data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.
The statement has been terminated.</Message>
```

My server side counterpart tells me that .NET is interpreting the date on the server side. He cannot tell me what format I should send it in.

My start date and end date are sent as string values.

I have tried:

d    2/27/2009
D    Friday, February 27, 2009
f    Friday, February 27, 2009 12:11 PM
F    Friday, February 27, 2009 12:12:22 PM
g    2/27/2009 12:12 PM
G    2/27/2009 12:12:22 PM
m    February 27
M    February 27
o    2009-02-27T12:12:22.1020000-08:00
O    2009-02-27T12:12:22.1020000-08:00
s    2009-02-27T12:12:22
t    12:12 PM
T    12:12:22 PM
u    2009-02-27 12:12:22Z
U    Friday, February 27, 2009 8:12:22 PM
y    February, 2009
Y    February, 2009

I have tried all of the above and I cannot get any of them to be accepted by the server.

I keep getting the error message:

The conversion of a datetime2 data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.
The statement has been terminated.

What should my date values look like to be accepted by .NET?

Comment: i believe there should be a certain documentation abt the date format of your .Net Date object. but i may suggest to send the date as a string and parse manually the string itself via regular expressions to create a Date instance.

Comment: This should be done on the server side, yes?